# How to write data at a particular position in c#?

Tags: c#, file

I am making an application in c#. In that application I have one byte array and I want to write that byte array data to particular position.

Here i used the following logic.

```
using(StreamWriter writer=new StreamWriter(@"D:\"+ FileName + ".txt",true))  
{  
    writer.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Data),IndexInFile,Data.Length);
}
```

But whenever i am writing data in file, it starts writing from starting.

My condition is that suppose at the initial I have empty file and I want to start writing in file from position 10000. Please help me .Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am getting error as 'System.IO.IOException: Unable seek backward to overwrite data that previously existed in a file opened in Append mode.
   at System.IO.FileStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Never try to write binary data as strings, like you do. It won't work correctly. Write binary data as binary data. You can use `Stream` for that instead of `StreamWriter`.

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    stream.Seek(1000, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
}
```

Comment: i used that but i am getting error as System.IO.IOException: Unable seek backward to overwrite data that previously existed in a file opened in Append mode.
   at System.IO.FileStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)

Comment: Then don't use `FileMode.Append`.

Comment: But i want to append the data.Then what i will do?

Comment: You can append only at the end of the file. You can't append in the middle of it.

Comment: IF i have to add the data at specified location in file.There may be already data present or not.Then what i should do?Please help me.And thanks for response.

Comment: Yes this code works. Instead of stream.Seek() you can also set stream.Position=value.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the position inside the stream like this:

```
writer.BaseStream.Seek( 1000, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Add this before your `WriteLine` code.

Note that I have not included any code to check that there is at least 1000 chars inside the file to start with.

Comment: I think `Seek()` works fine even if the file is not big enough. It fills the missing parts with zero bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The `WriteLine` overload you are using is this one:

[TextWriter.WriteLine Method (Char[], Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8x1ysa5.aspx)

In particular the `IndexInFile` argument supplied is actually the index in the *buffer* from which to begin reading **not** the index in the file at which to begin writing - this explains why you are writing at the start of the file not at `IndexInFile` as you expect.

You should obtain access to the underlying Stream and `Seek` to the desired position in the file first and then write to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit hacky, but you can access the `BaseStream` property of the `StreamWriter` and use `Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)` on it. (But be warned, as not every stream can use `Seek`.)