# Write some bytes in specific position in text file using c#

Tags: c#

I want to write this byte in `txt` file :

```
 byte[] TT = new byte[] { 0x28, 0x1A, 0x00, 0x49, 0xCB, 0xE8, 0xEF, 0x2B, 0x2C, 0x22, 0xB7, 0xBC, 0x54, 0xA1, 0x94, 0x6E };
```

and I want to write this byte in this position : 22530

I want the code in System.IO

I am using c#

Answer (score 2):

This should work. I'm a nice guy, but search around next time. It was pretty easy to find.

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    stream.Seek(1000, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
}
```

[How to write data at a particular position in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243122/how-to-write-data-at-a-particular-position-in-c)