# Append to the second to last line in a text file

Tags: c#

So I'm making a program to type what's in my clipboard into a text file, I plan on later transporting this information into an AHK script, but I want to do this all in one program, so if possible it will append to the .ahk file, but instead of it appending to the very last line, I need it to append to the line before return, which is the final line of the file.

```
Send ::redeem N4E2vzCEp {enter}
Sleep 1000
return
```

That's the end of the file, if possible I want my program to do something like:

```
string pasted = Clipboard.GetText();
sw.WriteLine.SecondLastLine("Send ::redeem " + pasted + " {enter}");
sw.WriteLine.SecondLastLine("Sleep 1000"); //Fully aware that secondlastline is not a valid command
```

But I don't know what the proper way of actually coding this would be.

Current code:

```
    private void paste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"c:\users\john\desktop\auths.txt";
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            string pasted = Clipboard.GetText();
            sw.WriteLine("Send ::redeem " + pasted + " {enter}");
            sw.WriteLine("Sleep 1000");
        }

    }
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service; Please update your question with the code you've tried so far.

Comment: In what frequency do you want to append a line?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand Ben, what do you mean by frequency? Every button press will append the clipboard to the text file

Comment: What I wanted to know was how often you append lines to the file. "By button pressed" answered this ;)

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243122/how-to-write-data-at-a-particular-position-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212127/add-a-new-line-at-a-specific-position-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is reading all lines into a `List` and then insert the new line at a specific position and write the lines back to the file.

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines("your file").ToList();
lines.Insert(lines.Count - 2, "new line");
File.WriteAllLines("your file", lines);
```

Comment: When I use this, it gives this:                                                                   
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'c:\users\john\desktop\auths.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: At what line do you get the exception?

Comment: on 25, which is this: List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList(); and 'path' is this: string path = @"c:\users\john\desktop\auths.txt";

Comment: Like the exception told you, there is another process which is accessing the file. Maybe the file is opened by another program or you have used it in your code before.

Comment: Only thing that has it open is notepad++, which I closed it out of that, and still gives the error. With the way I originally had it, I could have notepad++ open while using the program, and could press in notepad when I want to update it to the new changes.

Comment: Just saw thew streamwriter thing maybe it's whats doing it cause its technically pulling the path as well, so I commented it out to see if it fixes it

Comment: Make a new file (i.e. auths2.txt), a new path variable path2 and only use this variable in the code above. Just to make sure, you arn't using the file somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Okay, after some fiddling around with my clipboard, and commenting out sections of the code itself, it's working now. Thank you very much