# Writing to a binary file between an offset range

Tags: c#, binaryfiles

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uga7T.png)

I have coded an application to read all the bytes from a binary file within an offset range, in this case between offset 0x0000 AND 0x0003F
and I got the code correct.

I'm finding it difficult to write the code to take a value from the user. I need the code to take a value from the text box and replace all bytes between a specific offset range. For example, I type `"Rock"` inside the text box, so I need the program to write `'R'` at offset 0x000 `'O'` at offset 0X001 `'C'` at Offset 0X002 and so on when I hit write to file option.

This is the code I used to read from the binary file

```cs
OFD.ShowDialog();

BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(OFD.FileName));

for (int i = 0X00000; i <= 0x0003F; i++)
{

    br.BaseStream.Position = i;

    yobj += br.ReadByte().ToString("X2") + " ";

    rtb1.Text = yobj;

}
```

I managed to write the code in order to write each byte between a specific offset range, but the problem is it's writing the ASCII value of the first alphabet from the text box. I need the program to write the ASCII of each alphabet. I have provided the code below.

[Image 2:Writing to File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWfUU.png)

UPDATE- I managed to make the correct code.

[Image 3:Writing to File Correct Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDUCZ.png)

```
public void btnwrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OFD.ShowDialog();

    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(OFD.FileName));
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inp.Text);
    int[] result = Array.ConvertAll(bytes, Convert.ToInt32);

    for (int i= 0x0000;i<bytes.Length;i++)
    {
        bw.Seek(i, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        bw.Write(result[i]);
    }

    bw.Close();
}
```

Comment: Basically what you need to do is to convert your text to ASCII encoding first and then write bytes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243122/how-to-write-data-at-a-particular-position-in-c

Comment: Thanks, I managed to write the code in order to write each byte between a specific offset range, but the problem is its writing the ASCII value of the first alphabet from the textbox to all the bytes between the offset range. I need the program to write the ASCII of each alphabet. I have updated the first post. See image 2.

Comment: Update-Thanks again, i managed to correct the code myself.

Comment: The first post has been updated with the correct FileWriter code

Comment: if you find the correct answer by yourself please post it and accept as a correct answer

Comment: The idea of taking text, encoding it as ASCII, and then writing the resulting bytes to a file, is _well_-covered on Stack Overflow. See e.g. marked duplicate. Also: if you find a solution to your question, do **not** add the word "solved" or similar to the title. The Stack Overflow standard is to post an answer and accept it. Of course, there is no need for such answers on duplicate questions, so you won't be able to do that here. But please keep that in mind for future questions.